# Difference between lexical and syntax error

Tags: c, parsing

```
int 2ab;
int 2;
```

For above declarations, please tell which one is a lexical error and a syntax error in the C language. I am confused in both the declarations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both declarations are invalid, so you are rightfully confused, but for different reasons:

- A lexical error occurs when the compiler does not recognize a sequence of characters as a proper lexical token.  `2ab` is not a valid C token. (Note that `2ab` is a valid C preprocessing token that can be used in token pasting macros, but this seems beyond your current skill level).
- A syntax error occurs when a sequence of tokens does not match a C construction: statement, expression, preprocessing directive...  `int 2;` is a syntax error because a type starts a definition and a number is not an expected token in such a context: an identifier or possibly a `*`, a `(`, a specifier or a qualifier is expected.

Note that qualifiers and type or storage specifiers can appear in pretty much any order in C declarations:

```
int typedef const long cint;       // same as typedef const long int cint;
int volatile static short x;       // same as static volatile short int x;
int long unsigned long extern ll;  // same as extern unsigned long long int ll;
```

The above valid declarations are examples of variations you should **not** use `;-)`

Comment: OMG, that `typedef` doesn't have to be first blows me away!

Comment: @JohnHascall: my favorite motto: *learn something new everyday!* I've been using C for 35 years and I did not realize this until I wrote my third C parser.

Comment: @chqrlie, sorry, but `2ab` is recognized in C as **two** tokens (the number `2` , followed by the identifier `ab`)  A lexical error is for example an unterminated string (something as `"abc<end_of_line>`) which is invalid even as a single `"` character.

Comment: @LuisColorado: an unterminated string or character constant is indeed a lexical error, but I'm afraid you are mistaken regarding `2ab`: take a look at C11 6.4.8 Preprocessing numbers: *A preprocessing number begins with a digit optionally preceded by a period (.) and may be followed by valid identifier characters and the character sequences e+, e-, E+, E-, p+, p-, P+, or P-. Preprocessing number tokens lexically include all floating and integer constant tokens.*.

Comment: @LuisColorado: A preprocessing number is converted (as part of translation phase 7) to a floating constant token or an integer constant token. This conversion fails in the example: it is another type of lexical error.

Comment: So in the case of `int 2;`, a lexer wouldn't complain as `int` and `2` are both valid tokens if taken individually and will pass the ball to the parser, which in turn would raise an error because it doesn't understand what happens, correct?

Comment: @tonix: exactly! `int 2;` produces 3 tokens `int`, `2` and `;`. The parser cannot find a syntax rule that matches `int` followed `2`, hence it issues a syntax error and either stops parsing right away or tries some heuristic to parse further input, such as scanning for the next statement terminator `;`. The only reason to parse attempt to parse further input is to find further errors for the programmer to fix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How does the parser do it? It uses a finite-state machine, doesn't it? Could you advise some well known algorithms for correct syntax parsing?